# Application sound routing to different output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am using a USB audio interface (Alesis IO2 for what it's worth) on Ubuntu 22.04. This has historically worked fine.

Just today, I have had an issue where I can hear system sound through the audio interface (eg, changing audio volume, alert sounds, the test output portion of audio settings), but no application audio. The USB device is my selected output device, but if I open `pavucontrol`, I can see that application audio is being routed to the line out of my motherboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`pavucontrol` -> configuration -> changing the profile of the built-in device (motherboard line out) to "off" fixed this.

I guess somehow MS Teams managed to change this on me (this is what triggered the change, most likely)